# How to add parameter values to pgadmin sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters, pgadmin

In pgadmin3, I would like to use parameterized queries (to faster debugging, just copy & paste the query from my php file). But I haven't found an option to add the values of the `$1`, `$2`... parameters. Is it possible?

This is the query I'm building in a loop, following the suggestion for NULL testing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355733/1086511):

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM tax
              WHERE (addby=$1 or addby<>$1)
                    AND (adddate=$2 or adddate<>$2)
                    AND ($3 IS NULL AND nome IS NULL OR nome=$3)
                    AND ($4 IS NULL AND rank IS NULL OR rank=$4)
                    AND ($5 IS NULL AND pai IS NULL OR pai=$5)
                    AND ($6 IS NULL AND valido IS NULL OR valido=$6)
                    AND ($7 IS NULL AND sinonvalid IS NULL OR sinonvalid=$7)
                    AND ($8 IS NULL AND espec IS NULL OR espec=$8)
                    AND ($9 IS NULL AND public IS NULL OR public=$9)
       );
```

Notice that substitute all parameters by hand is tedious, error-prone and probably (I hope) unnecessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I only know two ways.

First is to use [`PREPARED STATEMENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) (Example after PostgreSQL Manual):

```
PREPARE usrrptplan (int) AS
    SELECT * FROM users u, logs l
    WHERE u.usrid=$1 AND u.usrid=l.usrid AND l.date = $2;

EXECUTE usrrptplan(1, current_date);
```

> PREPARE creates a prepared statement. 
>   When the PREPARE statement is executed, the specified statement is parsed, analyzed, and rewritten. When an EXECUTE command is subsequently issued, the prepared statement is planned and executed.
>
> Prepared statements can take parameters: values that are substituted into the statement when it is executed. When creating the prepared statement, refer to parameters by position, using $1, $2, etc.
>
> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session. When the session ends, the prepared statement is forgotten, so it must be recreated before being used again.

Second is to "find-and-replace" `$1`, `$2`, .. etc. by proper values. But you want to avoid this one.

Comment: sql developer just sends up a dialog prompt and lets you add them, even saves your last values, very handy

Comment: @chrismarx Nice feature. Sadly, pgadmin 4 did not introduce this feature.

Comment: I switched to DBeaver (https://dbeaver.com/), it supports params like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = :param1 AND col2 = :param2`

Answer (score 12):

In DBeaver you can use parameters in queries just like you can from code, so this will work:

```
select * from accounts where id = :accountId
```

When you run the query DBeaver will ask you for the value for :accountId and run the query.