# How to search when parameter is given but return all of the rows when it's null or empty?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I want to write a query that returns all rows when a given parameter in a `where` condition is null but when the parameter is not null return rows that match the condition, i am using `postgres 9.6` and here is what i have so far but no dice...

**Edit**

let me clarify the question

i have a prepared statement like this

```
select * from students where first_name like $1
```

what i want to do is when $1 is `null` ignore the `where` and return all students

**Thanks**

Comment: What programming language are you using here?

Comment: i am using Golang

Comment: how are you calling the query from go? Check for null in go, and either execute the query with the filter or with no filter.

Comment: that was my first thought but if it's possible i want to handle it with a single query

Comment: You *could* encapsulate the logic in a server-side function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353445/test-for-null-in-function-with-varying-parameters/17355733#17355733

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as below:

@FirstName is a parameter passed to the query:

```
select * from students where first_name like @FirstName or @FirstName is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is example of prepared statement with explicitly defined logic:

```
t=# prepare st(text) as select oid,datname 
from pg_database 
where case when $1 is null then true else datname like '%'||$1||'%' end;
PREPARE
t=# execute st('post');
  oid  | datname
-------+----------
 13505 | postgres
(1 row)

t=# execute st(null);
  oid  |  datname
-------+-----------
 13505 | postgres
 16384 | t
     1 | template1
 13504 | template0
 16419 | o
 16816 | db
(6 rows)
```