# Save multiple dynamic filter for aggregation in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, union, dynamic-sql

What is the **most efficient way to store multiple dynamic filter** which can be created by users on given data and us the filter for aggregating data?

Lets assume I have a table called `t_filter` which will store some data filter/queries for given data `t_data`.

The user can **build each filter completely** **dynamic** and can save it to create some kind of dashboard (list of the saved filter by filter_name and some aggregation function on the data which is filtered by the conditions).

Each filter can have different conditions and operators (`>=`, `<=`, `!=`, `==`, `IS NOT NULL`, `IS NULL`, `AND`, `OR`, `BETWEEN`, etc.) on the different fields of given entries in `t_data`.

**The user can modify its filter**: create/update/delete and the entries in `t_data` can grow through imports or shrink through deletes, so everything is kind of dynamic.

I solved this problem by creating dynamic SQL based on the created filter from the user, `UNION ALL` every of the existing dynamic SQL entries in `t_filter` and creating a **Materialized View** out of the result (just the foreign key information: which `filter_id` belongs to which data_id).

This solution works but is not that handy because I need to check for filter changes and regenerate the Materialized View as well as for new or deleted entries in `t_data`.

For every additional filter entry the time to generate the View is taking longer because of the extra SQL which needs to be executed.

Is there a better way to solve that problem?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353445/test-for-null-in-function-with-varying-parameters/17355733#17355733