# PREPARE stmt AS result of Concat in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration, concatenation

I'm sorry if this issue is so simple. I have some query that can run normally in MySQL Stored Procedure. But now I'm migrating it to PostgreSQL, that query is result of Concat from another query. The query simply like this:

```
DECLARE

A TEXT;

BEGIN

A = concate(sql);  /*in MySQL I just use SET A = CONCATE(sql)*/

PREPARE stmt AS A; /* in MySQL normally run with PREPARE stmt FROM A;*/
EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

But I always get an error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "A"
LINE 85:  PREPARE stmt AS A;
```

My questions are :

1. How can I access the variable `A` so it can run normally?
2. With or without `PREPARE`, is there any different of result when we run the query? If use `PREPARE` what is the advantages?

Thanks expert!

Comment: You should create a function . Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948131/postgresql-writing-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure-that-returns-a-result-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and use a prepared statement in PL/pgSQL, but bear in mind that PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE` is different from the SQL statement `EXECUTE`.

So if you want to execute a prepared statement in PL/pgSQL, you will have to use dynamic SQL to avoid the confusion between PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE` and the SQL statement of the same name.

```
DO $$BEGIN PREPARE x AS SELECT 42; END;$$;

EXECUTE x;

 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)

DO
$$DECLARE a integer;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'EXECUTE x' INTO a;
   RAISE NOTICE 'a = %', a;
END;$$;

NOTICE:  a = 42
```

Comment: Thanks sir, your explain so helpful. The query running well like your example.

When I search I didn't find like your explain. So the main different between MySQL and PostgreSQL when using `PREPARE` is with adding `EXECUTE` before `PREPARE label` and `'` (single quote) at `'PREPARE label'`. right?

Comment: I realize that my answer was confusing. Actually, you don't need dynamic SQL (PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE`) to run `PREPARE`, but you need it to run the SQL command `EXECUTE` in order to avoid confusion between these two kinds of `EXECUTE`. See my revised answer.