# Matching a substring against a stored list of strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

So, after the recent Twitch leak everyone is discussing their favorite bits of bad code. One bit that stood out was [a single monster SQL statement](https://www.reddit.com/r/badcode/comments/q2mkue/so_umm_this_is_from_twitch_source_code_leak/) to spot "illegal terms". That got me thinking about how to implement this "correctly".

So you have a table of strings that you want to match sub-strings against, how you write this in PL/pgSQL? I am assuming any SQL implementation should have procedural capabilities to create functions/procedures for such meta-programming, basically creating and executing SQL like the following:

```
admin@localhost:words> SELECT 'XabcY' LIKE '%abc%' OR 'XabcY' LIKE '%xyz%' as matches;
+-----------+
| matches   |
|-----------|
| True      |
+-----------+
```

So to be more specific, given a list of strings in table `disallowed`:

```
| illegal_string |
|----------------|
| stupid         |
| witless        |
| moron          |
| commie-lover   |
```

How would you create a dynamic query in PL/pgSQL that when executed returned true if any of these matched a given string? It does not need to use `ILIKE` in the Twitch like to check if the given word contained the substring, so using `position` is fine too, but it should be performant/tuneable using `gin` indices and whatnot.

[Related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047277/200987).

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. you can use `LIKE ANY(array)` operator

```
postgres=# select 'Ahoj' like any (ARRAY['Ah%', 'Na%']);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'Nazdar' like any (ARRAY['Ah%', 'Na%']);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

2. you can use regular expression:

```
postgres=# select 'Ahoj' ~ '^(Ah|Na)';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'Nazdar' ~ '^(Ah|Na)';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

So in the end you don't need dynamic SQL.

There are ANSI/SQL syntax too:

```
postgres=# select 'Nazdar' similar to '(Ah|Na)%';
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

So you can write something like:

```
DECLARE pw text[];
BEGIN
  pw := (SELECT array_agg('%' || disallowed || '%'
            FROM disallowed);
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE c LIKE ANY (pw)) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'there are some disallowed words';
  END IF;
  ...
```

I am not sure about an performance. On larger table you need trigram index, or maybe better is using fulltext instead substring searching.

Comment: > So in the end you don't need dynamic SQL.
Not sure I get you. How can I create the regex in the second option from a table? The regex needs to be built up from some kind of SELECT. With regards to the first option, I assume `ARRAY['Ah%', 'Na%']);` could be created from a `SELECT` on `illegal_words`. Not sure I get how the last procedural function works. What is `disallowed` referring to?

Comment: @oligofren - there was a bug in this example. I fixed it.
you can create fulltext index over your table, and very similarly you can write a query for searching some broken words. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: That might be, but could you expand version two to a full example? I do not understand how one would construct `select 'Ahoj' ~ '^(Ah|Na)'` from selecting on `illegal_words`, which is basically the original question :)

Comment: @oligofren - you can use subselect `select 'Ahoj' ~ (select string_agg(ilegal_words, '|') from disallowed) from ...`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you need PL/pgSQL or dynamic SQL for this. Make a set of text from the table of disallowed words and match against the set items as regular expressions. Maybe not very performant using regexp magic, but I hope straightforward. The query below can of course be parameterized.

```sql
select '<text to examine>' ~* 
  any(select illegal_string from disallowed) as rude;
```

```sql
select 'You Stupido MORONE!' ~* 
  any(select illegal_string from disallowed) as rude;
-- yields true.
```

You may wish to restrict the search to whole words only. Then play with the regexp set and shape it like this:

```sql
select 'You Stupido MORONE!' ~* 
  any(select '\m'||illegal_string||'\M' from disallowed) as rude;
-- yields false
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/944fd6/11)