# Getting error in EXECUTE statement when a null value is encountered

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have created following stored procedure to update `recon_dashboard` table.

```
create or replace procedure ca_adhoc_view.sp_count_recon_refresh()
    language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
    f record;
BEGIN
    for f in select alvid from ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard
    loop
    raise notice '% alv',f.alv;
    execute 'update ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard set alv_count = 
            (select count(*) from ' || f.alv  || ')

     where id='|| f.id;
end loop;
END;
$$;
```

It works fine unless there is a null value in the `alv`, then it throws an error.
I tried to check for null like:

```
create or replace procedure ca_adhoc_view.sp_count_recon_refresh()
    language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
    f record;
BEGIN
    for f in select alv,id from ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard
    loop
    raise notice '% alv',f.alv;
    execute 'update ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard set alv_count = 
    (IF '||f.alv||' is not null
        then (select count(*) from ' || f.alv  || ')
    END IF;)
     where id='|| f.id;
end loop;
END;
$$;
```

But it throws error when I try to call the SP.

```
Error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ca_view"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function "sp_count_recon_refresh" line 7 at execute statement
```

In error "ca_view" is a recod. `alv` column has values like 'ca_view.table1', 'ca_view.table2' and so on.

Comment: `alvid` or `alv, id`? The former looks like a typo. Please proofread your question. Postgres version? Core definition of `ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard` (`CREATE TABLE` statement)?

Answer (score 2):

This probably fixes your problems:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ca_adhoc_view.sp_count_recon_refresh()
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   f record;
BEGIN
   FOR f IN
      SELECT alv, id FROM ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '% alv', f.alv;
      IF f.alv IS NOT NULL THEN
         EXECUTE format(
            'UPDATE ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard
             SET    alv_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM %I)
             WHERE  id = $1', f.alv)
         USING   f.id;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

"Problems" (plural). Besides defending against a NULL value for the table name with proper syntax, this also prevents **SQL injection**. Your original is wide open there. Related:

- [PostgreSQL - Writing dynamic sql in stored procedure that returns a result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948131/postgresql-writing-dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure-that-returns-a-result-set/12047277#12047277)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

That said, it would be more efficient to run a single `UPDATE` instead of updating one row per loop iteration. Consider building and executing a single statement.